# WPF execute ICommand using attached properties and behaviours

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, attached-properties

So I'm learning about attached properties and attached behaviours. I have a `TextBox` and everytime the text is changed, I want to execute some `ICommand SomeCommand` in my ViewModel which I would bind in the view like this:

```
<TextBox ... TextUpdateCommand="{Binding Path=SomeCommand}" MonitorTextBoxProperty=true />
```

`MonitorTextBoxProperty` is just a property that listens to `TextChanged` event and then executes `ICommand SomeCommand` when `TextChanged` is fired. The `ICommand SomeCommand` that is executed should come from `TextUpdateCommandProperty`. How do I link this `ICommand SomeCommand` to execute it from `OnTextBoxTextChanged`?

Code:

```
//Property and behaviour for TextChanged event

public static int GetMonitorTextBoxProperty(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (int)obj.GetValue(MonitorTextBoxProperty);
}

public static void SetMonitorTextBoxProperty(DependencyObject obj, int value)
{
    obj.SetValue(MonitorTextBoxProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MonitorTextBoxProperty =
     DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("MonitorTextBox", typeof(bool), typeof(this), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnMonitorTextBoxChanged));

private static void OnMonitorTextBoxChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = (d as TextBox);
    if (textBox == null) return;

    textBox.TextChanged -= OnTextBoxTextChanged;

    if ((bool)e.NewValue)
    {
        textBox.TextChanged += OnTextBoxTextChanged;
    }
}

private static void OnTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
 {
    // Execute ICommand by command.Execute()
 }

// Property for attaching ICommand that is executed on TextChanged

public static int GetTextUpdateCommandProperty(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (int)obj.GetValue(TextUpdateCommandProperty);
}

public static void SetTextUpdateCommandProperty(DependencyObject obj, int value)
{
    obj.SetValue(TextUpdateCommandProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty TextUpdateCommandProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TextUpdateCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(this), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get the current value of the `TextBox`'s `TextUpdateCommand` property using the attached property's get accessor. Try this:

```
private static void OnTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox = sender as TextBox;
    var command = GetTextUpdateCommandProperty(textBox);
    if (command != null)
         command.Execute(null);
}
```

You should also change the type of the accessors:

```
public static ICommand GetTextUpdateCommandProperty(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (ICommand)obj.GetValue(TextUpdateCommandProperty);
}

public static void SetTextUpdateCommandProperty(DependencyObject obj, ICommand value)
{
    obj.SetValue(TextUpdateCommandProperty, value);
}
```

And `typeof(this)` should the `typeof(TheClassName)` in the call to  `DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached`.

Comment: Of course, it was a pretty simple solution I did not notice. Thanks :) Thanks for correcting the little mistakes as well, I discovered them afterwards myself